# `vc-root-dir` is not a valid command name

Tags: commands

Trying to use the `vc-root-dir` function on Emacs gives the error message `vc-root-dir is not a valid command name`

On inspecting `vc.elc` as found by `locate-library` the function appears to exist as a defalias.

emacs-version is 26.1 FYI

Comment: Does it work if you evaluate the command with `M-:` aka `M-x eval-expression RET (vc-root-dir) RET`?  If so, then the answer is that the function works correctly, but is not made for interactive use.  If we type `M-x find-function RET vc-root-dir RET` we can inspect the function and see that it does not contain an `(interactive ...)` statement after the doc-string.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @lawlist thanks that was indeed the problem - just not understanding debugging i suppose

Answer (score 1):

The function `vc-root-dir` is a non-interactive function and Emacs will generate the error described by the original poster if said function is called interactively.  It is often helpful to visit the function at issue to see what makes it tick, and this can be done with `M-x find-function`.  Non-interactive functions can be evaluated in a variety of ways, such as `M-x eval-expression` aka `M-:`.